# if undefined or empty or indexOf match then

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function where an option can get passed in. The option is for specifying a restriction, and thus if the option is undefined, null, or an empty array then no restriction applies and all data rows get tested. If an array of options is provided, then only the data rows matching one of the restrictions gets whacked.

That is, the function needs to test every element of a data array and then also optionally do a check against the restriction option if a restriction option has been provided.

**Is there a shorter way to write the test?**

```
function dostuff (data, option) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if ((test(data[i].x) && !option) ||
        (test(data[i].x) && !option.length) ||
        (test(data[i].x) && Array.isArray(option) && option.length && option.indexOf(data[i].y) != -1)
       ) // ZOMG! Can this be shorter?
    {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

---

ps. I'm not after some impossible to read chunk of code golf black magic. Just something that's shorter and succinct and sensible.

Comment: please add some calls of the function and the wanted results.

Comment: well (test(data[i].x) does not need to be tested on every line....

Answer (score 0):

You only need to test for restrictions if restrictions are present, so just check to see if the options array is defined & has elements before worrying about doing anything with your data.

If the options array has elements, then you can use nested loops to check each element in data against each element in option. If the option passes your checks do whatever processing you need:

```
function dostuff (data, option) {
  // Option MUST be an array with length 
  // if you're going to check data against the options
  // so:
  if(typeof option !== 'undefined' && option.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      for(var p = 0; p < option.length; p++) {
        if(test(data[i].x) [AGAINST] option[p] [IS ALLOWED]) {
          processDataAsNeeded(data[i].x);
        } else {
          // Nothing needs to happen here, as data[i].x was restricted by option[p]
        }
      }
    }
  } else { // Here there are no restrictions, so process everything
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        processDataAsNeeded(data[i].x);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite - the function needs to test every element of an array and if there are no restrictions do stuff if the element meets some test(); or if there are restrictions then only do stuff if both test() && the restriction also matches.

Comment: @Erics When you say 'needs to test every element of an array' do you mean test every element of the data array or every element of the option array?

Comment: Always test every element of the data array, and also test against the restriction if specified.

Comment: Answer updated - is that more inline with what you're looking to do?

Comment: What is this `test() [AGAINST] option[p] [IS ALLOWED]` thing? Is that a comment?

Comment: That's pseudo-code because I can't tell exactly how your checks are working, but my guess is that's where you would put `option[p].indexOf(data[i].x) != -1`

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood correctly, I think you can reduce the if statement to something like:

```
if (typeof(option) == "undefined" || !option.length) {
  continue;
} else {
  if (test(data[i].x)) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

or shorter ..

```
if ( !(typeof(option) == "undefined" || option.length) ) {
  if (test(data[i].x)) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```